# В чём отличие isBlank vs isEmpty?

Tags: java, android, строки

В чём отличие isBlank vs isEmpty?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Из документации [StringUtils](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-2.6/org/apache/commons/lang/StringUtils.html):

> **isBlank(String str)** checks if a String is whitespace, empty (`""`) or null.
>
> ```
> StringUtils.isBlank(null)      = true  
> StringUtils.isBlank("")        = true  
> StringUtils.isBlank(" ")       = true  
> StringUtils.isBlank("bob")     = false  
> StringUtils.isBlank("  bob  ") = false
> ```
>
> **isEmpty(String str)** checks if a String is empty (`""`) or null.
>
> ```
> StringUtils.isEmpty(null)      = true
> StringUtils.isEmpty("")        = true
> StringUtils.isEmpty(" ")       = false
> StringUtils.isEmpty("bob")     = false
> StringUtils.isEmpty("  bob  ") = false
> ```

Т.е. разница в проверке пробела:

```
StringUtils.isBlank(" ") = true
StringUtils.isEmpty(" ") = false
```

Comment: Я просто балдею от контегента наших java-истов. Ладно ТС, принявший ответ, но из остальных 15-ти Хоть бы кто в сорсы глянул перед плюсованием. Из isBlank() -- `... if ((Character.isWhitespace(str.charAt(i)) == false)) {
                    return false; }...`.  При этом, хотя слово "whitespace" из документации присутствует, **никто** не обратил внимания, что оно *шире*, чем пробел. Т.е. в понятие whitespace помимо **пробела `\u0020`** входят -- **'\u00A0', '\u2007', '\u202F', '\u0009', '\u000A', '\u000B', '\u000C', '\u000D', '\u001C', '\u001D', '\u001E', '\u001F'**.

Answer (score 5):

isBlank = isEmpty + допускает наличие пробелов

```
 isBlank(null)      = true
 isBlank("")        = true  
 isBlank(" ")       = true  

 isEmpty(null)      = true
 isEmpty("")        = true  
 isEmpty(" ")       = false
```

Answer (score 2):

- `isEmpty` - проверяет, является ли строка пустой ("") или значение `null`.
- `isBlank` - проверяет, есть-ли в строке пробел, пустая строка ("") или значение `null`.
- [isEmpty](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-2.6/org/apache/commons/lang/StringUtils.html#isEmpty(java.lang.String))
- [isBlank](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-2.6/org/apache/commons/lang/StringUtils.html#isBlank(java.lang.String))

Comment: Наверное всё же `null`, а не `NULL`.

Answer (score 0):

isEmpty - возвращает true только если строка абсолютно пустая ("") или имеет значение null;

isBlank - возвращает true только если в строке есть только пробел(-ы) (и нет других символов) или строка пустая ("") или имеет значение null.

прикладное значение: допустим мы хотим чтобы пользователь ввёл свое имя, чтобы поприветствовать его.

Пользователь вводит пробел(-ы) вместо имени, тогда получится "Привет, пробел(-ы)".

Чтобы не здороваться с пробелом можно проверить введенное имя через isBlank() и в случае если пользователь ввел только пробел(-ы) попросить заново ввести имя.

Comment: isBlank проверяет так называемые **whitespace**, в их число кроме обычного пробела входят символы табуляции, новой строки и т.п. (полюбопытствуйте, раскручивая [отсюда](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-2.6/org/apache/commons/lang/StringUtils.html#isBlank(java.lang.String)) (если кликнуть на название метода, покажет его сорсы))